# Bash shell alias not working as expected

Tags: bash, shell

I'm trying to write a shell script that uses LibreOffice to convert an .odt document to .pdf, but getting stuck on an alias issue. I have the following line in my `~/.bash_profile`:

```
alias soffice='/Applications/LibreOffice.app/Contents/MacOS/soffice'
```

There's the following line in my shell script:

```
soffice --headless --convert-to pdf $filename
```

that creates a "line 14: soffice: command not found" error. I'm not sure what's going on because I can call

```
$ alias
alias soffice='/Applications/LibreOffice.app/Contents/MacOS/soffice'
```

and

```
$ soffice --headless --convert-to pdf thefile.odt
```

also works fine. Does anybody know why the alias isn't working in my script and what I can do about it? Thanks.

Comment: what is the content of $filename ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The other answers try to solve this globally, so I will add an answer that will solve your problem in your current script (without aliases, which normally shouldn't be used in scripts).

The most appropriate answer to your question might be to add the directory to your PATH, i.e. adding it to your *~/.bashrc* like @Palec suggested. That would make your alias unnecessary. If you just want to solve this for this script you can add it to your PATH right in the script! Put this somewhere in the top of your script (before running the soffice command):

```
export PATH="$PATH:/Applications/LibreOffice.app/Contents/MacOS/soffice"
```

Actually you probably don't need the *export* here.

Another option is setting soffice as a variable, i.e.:

```
soffice="/Applications/LibreOffice.app/Contents/MacOS"

$soffice --headless --convert-to pdf thefile.odt
```

...but that is just a convenience for

```
/Applications/LibreOffice.app/Contents/MacOS/soffice --headless --convert-to pdf thefile.odt
```

which is totally OK for a one-off command in a personal script. For a wider public a safer route, like PATH, would be preferred.

Comment: The variable contents is missing `/soffice` at the end.

Comment: +1; specifically, `export` is needed if _other_ scripts or executables invoked by the script at hand should also see the modified `$PATH`; also, while not strictly needed in this particular case, it's generally safer to double-quote the variable containing the executable name, i.e.: `"$soffice" --headless --convert-to pdf thefile.odt`

Answer (score 5):

By default, bash aliases are expanded only in interactive shells, not in scripts.

Generally, this is a good thing because most scripts are written assuming that they are using real commands not aliased ones.  For example, many people alias `rm` to `rm -i` and `mv` to `mv -i`.  For interactive work, this is good: it lets you know if you mistyped something and are attempting to delete the wrong file.  For a shell script, which might be moving many files, it becomes awkward quickly.  Further, if the shell script has redirected stdin, something unexpected will happen.

So, it is good practice to avoid using aliases in shell scripts.

If you do want the `soffice` shortcut available to scripts *without* enabling aliases, create a file called `soffice` with the contents:

```
#!/bin/sh
exec /Applications/LibreOffice.app/Contents/MacOS/soffice "$@"
```

Add custom options as you like, make it executable, and put it somewhere on your path.

If you know that you are not going to want any custom options or custom directory, an alternative is to create a symlink:

```
ln -s /Applications/LibreOffice.app/Contents/MacOS/soffice /somewhere/on/your/path/soffice
```

Many people add `$HOME/bin` to their path and put all such symlinks and shell scripts there.

**More Approaches:**  This question has a lot of answers:

For more on PATH-based solutions, see the answers by [@Palec](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21490711/3030305) and [@Bryn](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21491486/3030305) .

For how to use functions which, unlike aliases, can be exported, see [@glenn jackman's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21491049/3030305).

If you still want to use aliases, see the answers by [@mklement0](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21490694/3030305) and [@user202988](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21490730/3030305)

Comment: While I have used the wrapper script method for putting things in path a lot, it is mostly a good idea if you really need certain options set every time - i.e. I do this with programs that don't have a config file (and aliases don't fit). If you don't need this (and don't want to put the directory in your PATH) you might as well make a symlink - `ln -s /Applications/LibreOffice.app/Contents/MacOS/soffice /somewhere/in/your/path/`

Answer (score 3):

## Direct answer

You should use `PATH` environment variable instead of defining an alias.

```
export PATH="/Applications/LibreOffice.app/Contents/MacOS:$PATH"
```

Put this line inside your `~/.bashrc` or a similar initialization script. This way it is passed through environment to every process spawned from Bash. You can also use the setting just for the current Bash instance if you only call it there.

## On `PATH` generally

[`PATH`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PATH_%28variable%29) is a colon-separated (`:`) list of directories with executables. When shell executes a command, it looks into these directories for executable of the same name. Directories are tried in left-to-right order, the first executable found is used. You can see which of the executables is used via `which` command:

```
$ which cat
/bin/cat
```

One directory name could surprise you in `PATH`. Empty string. You can see it as a colon at either end of `PATH` or as `::` somewhere in the middle. It has the same effect as specifying `.` (current directory). It is in `PATH` in Windows by default, but usually not in *nixes.

## Good configuration

Generally it is a good idea to include your personal executables directories in `PATH` as any newly added executable will be available immediately, without need to write yet another alias. On *nixes, users usually have `~/bin` for their privately installed software. However, `~` is usually expanded by shell on command line, but not between double quotes. In `PATH` it has no special meaning. Use `HOME` environment variable instead as it is expanded correctly:

```
export PATH="$HOME/bin:$PATH"
```

Always place new directories at the beginning. Executable of the same name as one of those already installed in the system takes precedence when placed into `~/bin` then. Overriding the default version of the tool is usually desired.

My settings:

```
palec@Palec:~$ echo "$PATH"
/home/palec/www/ksp/web/bin:/home/palec/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin
```

This is typical. `/bin` for the most basic programs, `/usr/bin` for both still pretty basic programs and most of globally installed software, `/usr/local/bin` for machine-specific, self-compiled and third-party software. Then my personal `~/bin` and for a project I contribute to `~/www/ksp/web/bin`. More info on [`/usr` contents](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/Linux-Filesystem-Hierarchy/html/usr.html) can be found in TLDP.

Comment: Might be nit-picking, but in my head the convention is to append to PATH (unless you really need to prepend) :) ...appended PATHs takes precedence over previous PATHs, which is useful (or confusing) if you have multiple executables with the same name in your PATH. In example, installing a newer version of a program in _/usr/local/bin_ (which comes after _/usr/bin_) will make it your preferred version.

Comment: @bryn I agree that more local executables should take precedence over the more global. Personal choice should override the system defaults. Now as I read [Wikipedia article on `PATH`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PATH_%28variable%29) and tested it via `printf '#!/bin/sh\necho "Will not tell!"' > date; chmod +x date; export PATH='/bin:'; date; export PATH=':/bin'; date; rm date`, I found that my version is actually correct in this regard. `PATH` is searched from left to right. My `PATH` is `/home/palec/www/ksp/web/bin:/home/palec/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin`. Please remove your comment.

Answer (score 2):

Aliases are by default not expanded in *scripts*.

To change that, run `shopt -s expand_aliases` at the top of your script.

**Update**:

@user202988's answer correctly implies that a *script doesn't inherit its parent shell's aliases*, so you have two options:

- `source` them from a file, as @user202988 suggests (in the simplest case: from your shell profile) - while convenient, this wholesale import can result in inadvertent alias expansions.
- alternatively, simply define only the required aliases at the top of your script itself.

And, finally, listen to @John1024's advice about avoiding aliases in scripts altogether. :)

Answer (score 2):

If you look into the bash manpage you find:

> Aliases are not expanded when the shell is not interactive, unless the
>   expand_aliases shell option is set using shopt (see the description of
>   shopt under SHELL BUILTIN COMMANDS below).

So put a

```
shopt -s expand_aliases
```

in your script.

Make sure to source your aliases file after setting this in your script.

```
shopt -s expand_aliases
source ~/.bash_aliases
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a function and export it. Then a bash script will be able to use it:

```
$ myfunction() { echo do something here: "$@"; }
$ export -f myfunction

$ cat foo.sh
#!/bin/bash
myfunction with extra args

$ ./foo.sh
do something here: with extra args
```

Of course, that's pretty fragile as it depends on *your* environment. Put these special functions in a separate file that you can `source` both from your .bashrc and from the script.